# Django render function takes forever to load

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a function definition in the `views.py` file of my Django app as follows:

```py
def dashboard_page(request, date_range=None):
    ''' This is the function '''

    template = 'accounts/dashboard.html'
    dashboard_data_url = reverse('dashboard_data')

    return render(request, template, {'dashboard_data_url': dashboard_data_url})
```

The `Templates` configuration on the `settings.py` file is as follows:

```py
DEBUG = False

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates/'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I tried to debug the issue using the `pdb` and got the following error as shown in the screenshot. I tried to add print statements before the render function, that works fine. But the render function takes forever and returns no response.

[image: Python Debugger output 1]

[image: Python Debugger output 2]

Comment: I have also tried keeping the `'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')]` inside `TEMPLATES` config in the `settings.py` file.

Comment: What do you have in `'accounts/dashboard.html'` ?

Comment: It's a simple HTML file with some hello world text.